# giving a query as part of a uri in autobench

Tags: autobench

I am using autobench for doing becnhmark. An example of autobench command is as shown below.

```
autobench --single_host --host1 testhost.foo.com --uri1 /index.html --quiet 
          --timeout 5 --low_rate 20 --high_rate 200 --rate_step 20 --num_call 10
          --num_conn 5000 --file bench.tsv**
```

The uri which I have to specify has a query attached to it.  When I run the command which has the query, I get the following result

```
dem_req_rate    req_rate_localhost  con_rate_localhost  min_rep_rate_localhost  avg_rep_rate_localhost  max_rep_rate_localhost  stddev_rep_rate_localhost   resp_time_localhost net_io_localhost    errors_localhost
 200    0   20  0   0   0   0   0   0   101
 400    0   40  0   0   0   0   0   0   101
 600    0   60  0   0   0   0   0   0   101
 800    0   80  0   0   0   0   0   0   101
1000    0   100 0   0   0   0   0   0   101
1200    0   120 0   0   0   0   0   0   101
1400    0   140 0   0   0   0   0   0   101
1600    0   160 0   0   0   0   0   0   101
1800    0   180 0   0   0   0   0   0   101
2000    0   200 0   0   0   0   0   0   101
```

The query request, response are all zeroes.  Can anybody please tell me how to give a query as part of the uri?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me when I surrounded the uri containing the query string in single quotes. Something like:

uri1 '/my/uri/query?string'